# How to add embedded chat button on all the community pages one at a time

Tags: lightning-community, chat, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, force.com-embedded

I have 150+ community pages on all the community page i want to add embedded chat button. Right now i have to go to every page and drag the embedded chat into it which is very much time consuming process. Is there any way we can add embedded chat button on all the pages from one place in community.